# Procedure or function 'SpMyIndex' expects parameter '@pro_ID', which was not supplied

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm using this stored procedure that expects `@pro_ID` parameter value:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SpMyIndex]
    @pro_ID int
AS
    SELECT CAST(MAX(SUBSTRING(thumbpic_path, 18, 1)) AS INT)+1 AS HAHA
    FROM [dbo].[TblPro_Gallery] WHERE pro_ID = @pro_ID
```

In my code I have a DropDownList (`drpProduct`) that must deliver the `@pro_ID` to `SqlDataSource`:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdsMyIndex" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DigiStudio_CString %>" 
    SelectCommand = "[SpMyIndex]" SelectCommandType= "StoredProcedure">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="drpProduct" Name="pro_ID" 
            PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

and this is my C# code:

```
private void MakeIndex()
{
             SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cn);

             SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
             cmd = con.CreateCommand();
             cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
             cmd.CommandText = "[SpMyIndex]";

             con.Open();

             SqlDataReader dbDR = cmd.ExecuteReader();

             while (dbDR.Read())
             {
                 Session["MyIndex"] = dbDR["HAHA"].ToString();
             }

             con.Close();
     }
```

Why the can't the stored procedure access value of `@pro_ID`?

Comment: Since your sp expect an `int` parameter, and because you didn't add your `@pro_ID` parameter value in your stored procedure? Like; `cmd.Parameters.AddValue("@pro_ID", yourvalue)`

Comment: You have a `SqlDataSource` in your markup, with the parameter set up correctly - but in your **code**, you're using a stand-alone `SqlCommand` which does **NOT** get a `@pro_ID` parameter defined! Why do you set up a `SqlDataSource` in your markup, and then use a separate, independent `SqlCommand` to get the data?? Use one or the other - having both doesn't make any sense at all

Answer (score 0):

Since your are using asp:SqlDataSource , you dont need to write the code which you have written in MakeIndex method. If you are taking the route of MakeIndex method, then you have to add @pro_ID as command parameter. I think you are mixing here approaches.

Comment: I Remove the SqlDataSource and add @pro_ID to my C# code and it works...

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pro_ID", drpProduct.SelectedValue.ToString());